# get() method on dict to get a subvalue

Tags: python

I have a dict where I want to say "if there is a category, then get the category icon. If not, return `''`".

I'm doing it to add the icon to a string:

```
'Icon: %s' % venue.get('category', '').get('icon', 'No Icon')
```

Obviously if there is no category, `get()` throws an error. Here are a couple other wrong ways to do this:

```
venue.get('category[icon]', '')

venue.get('category', '')['icon']
```

Hopefully that illustrates what I'm trying to do. Is there a way to do this without an if/else statement?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use an if/else statement? It would enhance code readability AND it would do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the default value an empty dictionary:

```
'Icon: %s' % venue.get('category', {}).get('icon', 'No Icon')
```

However, that incurs the overhead of an empty dictionary creation every time it runs. If performance is important to you, try:

```
'Icon: %s' % (venue['category'].get('icon', 'No Icon') if 'category' in venue else 'No Icon')
```

There are many other possible ways to approach this, quite possibly even more efficient than the above (the above makes two lookups for `'category'` if it is found).

Comment: In the first snippet, you could use `venue.setdefault('category', {})...` instead of `venue.get(...)`. Then, if there were no dict associated with the category, a new one would be created on the first access. Here's a [reference doc](http://starship.python.net/~mwh/hacks/setdefault.html).

Comment: Also, you could get around the extra overhead problem by merely declaring an empty dict in the previous line. That way you'd just repeatedly reference the same dict.

Comment: Well, if you do that then you would want to declare a global *once* such as `EMPTY_DICT = {}` otherwise you would still create a new empty dictionary on the previous line.